# Mysql table column holds database name -> select transactions from that referenced database?

Tags: mysql, reference

hopefully I'm being clear enough..

I have this mysql setup where I have one central database (named Central) which has an accounts table which holds all the user accounts and then for every user there is a separate database holding their transactions.

The central table looks something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Central.accounts (
    ID int UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    UserID int(10) NOT NULL,
    DatabaseRef varchar(20)
)
```

i would like to do the following: Fetch all rows from the Transactions table in the Database that is referenced to by the  Central.accounts -> DatabaseRef column

```
SELECT * FROM [CA.DatabaseRef].Transactions T

JOIN Central.accounts CA ON CA.ID = T.UserID

WHERE CA.UserID = 2
```

Is this possible some way? Ultimately i would like to do this in one query and not do it with php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Statements for such a query.

Of course the lasz part doesn't work , because there is no such database or table.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE accounts (
>     ID int UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
>     UserID int(10) NOT NULL,
>     DatabaseRef varchar(20)
> );
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO accounts VALUES (NULL,2,'test');
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT DatabaseRef INTO @sql FROM accounts WHERE UserID = 2;
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT @sql;
> ```
>
> ```
> | @sql |
> | :--- |
> | test |
> ```

> ```
> SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM ',@sql,'.Transactions T WHERE T.UserID = 2');
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT @sql;
> ```
>
> ```
> | @sql                                                 |
> | :--------------------------------------------------- |
> | SELECT * FROM test.Transactions T WHERE T.UserID = 2 |
> ```

> ```
> PREPARE test FROM @sql;
> EXECUTE test;
> ```
>
> ```
> SELECT command denied to user 'u_1350201779'@'localhost' for table 'Transactions'
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b83a5363b6c770c85f405fb5a96aebc7)*